# Right-align two parts of a string

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'd like to itemize the input of data in the following format (columns 2 & 3 are right-aligned).

```
Flange Inside Diameter                     B         987.000  mm
Flange Outside Diameter                    A        1500.000  mm
Flange Thickness                           t        240.0000  mm
Thickness of Hub at Small End             g0         40.0000  mm
Thickness of Hub at Large End             g1         80.0000  mm
Length of Hub                              h         60.0000  mm
```

I think one approach might be RSET function:

```
Dim P_Des As Double Dim MyString1

MyString1 = Space(40) RSet MyString1 = "B0"
Debug.Print "Flange Inside Diameter" & MyString1 & " mm"
```

Comment: Please post an expected desired result. As of now your question **is too unclear to be answered**

Comment: @Rawrplus my expected result is the the ones in the lines I've commented out: I need series of string to be right-aligned. I've written a code, posted in the answer section. Any better idea?

Comment: And what do you want the string to be right aligned for? As output into cells for worksheet or?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Right(Space(40) & "Your Text", 40)
```

Later you can TRIM the spaces in case you need to.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Public Function AlignString(ByVal String1 As String, ByVal String2 As String, ByVal String3 As String, Optional String4 As String = "mm", _
                        Optional bSpace1 As Byte = 40, Optional bSpace2 As Byte = 4, Optional bSpace3 As Byte = 16) As String

```
Dim sStringvar1 As String
Dim sStringvar2 As String
Dim sStringvar3 As String

sStringvar1 = Space(bSpace1)
sStringvar2 = Space(bSpace2)
sStringvar3 = Space(bSpace3)

LSet sStringvar1 = String1
RSet sStringvar2 = String2
RSet sStringvar3 = String3
AlignString = " " & sStringvar1 & sStringvar2 & sStringvar3 & "  " & String4
```

End Function